# WPF change grid.row and grid.column

Tags: wpf

when I have a grid and I add rows later does i have to change all the grid.row attributes or exists a trick to give the rowdefinition a index or something?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean design time? then you need to change the Grid.Row attribute; nothing there as variables.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to set the Grid.Row/Grid.Column attached properties of the child elements that you add to the Grid.

Unfortunately (?) a XAML Grid is *not* like an HTML table in the sense that you can add elements to a specific row or column of it without setting an attached property of the element itself that specifies where in the Grid the element should be located.